# Java Joda time Daylight savings time

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, datetime-format

I am having difficulty using JodaTime to handle Daylight savings time.

```
 String time = "3:45-PM";   
 DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("KK:mm-a");
 DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(time).withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York"));
 dt = dt.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);

 startDate = startDate.withHourOfDay(dt.getHourOfDay()).withMinuteOfHour(dt.getMinuteOfHour());
```

Output from this code snippet ends up being:

```
2015-04-08 16:46:51.952  INFO 12244 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] VALUES PULLED                        : 03:45-PM
2015-04-08 16:46:51.952  INFO 12244 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] VALUES PULLED                        : 08:45-PM
```

Currently, the time is 5 hours off. Which is not handling Daylights saving time. How do I get Joda Time to take DLS into account?

Comment: Did you try calling `startDate.`[`toLocalDateTime()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#toLocalDateTime())?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the `DateTime` object that you get after parsing is set to the date `01-01-1970`. It looks like you expect that it would be set to today, but it isn't.

If you want the time to be interpreted as 3:45 PM today in the timezone `America/New_York`, do this:

```
String time = "3:45-PM";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("KK:mm-a")
        .withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York"));

DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(time)
        .withDate(LocalDate.now());

System.out.println(dt);

System.out.println(dt.withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC));
```

Note: You need to set the zone on the `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: What you suggested work aside from 2 things.

for
     .withDate(), it requires 3 ints, not a LocalDate.now(). But that was a simple fix. 

the other things is that one should not do this line: startDate = startDate.withHourOfDay(dt.getHourOfDay()).withMinuteOfHour(dt.getMinuteOfHour()); It loses the conversion and has abnormal behavior. Using localDate.now() was a better solution. Thank you.

Comment: @user1420688 about `withDate` needing 3 ints: maybe you're using a different (older) version of the Joda Time library that doesn't have the version of `withDate` that takes a `LocalDate`.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

Quoted below is a notice at the [Home Page of Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Joda-Time is the de facto standard date and time library for Java
> prior to Java SE 8. Users are now asked to migrate to java.time
> (JSR-310).

**Solution using *java.time*, the modern API:**

You need to combine the current date with the time.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strTime = "3:45-PM";
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");

        LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(strTime, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:m-a", Locale.ENGLISH));
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now(zoneId);
        LocalDateTime ldt = date.atTime(time);
        System.out.println(ldt);

        // Date-time at UTC
        System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.of(ldt, zoneId).toInstant());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-05-08T15:45
2021-05-08T19:45:00Z
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>